# Translation of the official "how to answer"

Tags: discussion, help-translated

Original:

> ## How do I write a good answer?
>
> Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great:
>
> #### Pay it forward
>
> Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.
>
> #### Have the same problem?
>
> Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on. You can also vote up the question or [set a bounty](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on it so the question gets more attention.
>
> #### Answer the question
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.
>
> #### Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.
>
> #### Write to the best of your ability
>
> We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it.
>
> #### Answer [well-asked](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) questions
>
> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
>
> - ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
> - ...solicit [opinions](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) rather than facts.
> - ...have [already been asked](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search) and answered many times before.
> - ...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions.
> - ...are not about Ukrainian language as [defined in the help center](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
>
> Don't forget that you can edit the question you're answering to improve the clarity and focus - this can reduce the chances of the question being closed or deleted.
>
> #### Always be polite and have fun
>
> It’s fine to disagree and express concern, but please be civil. There’s a real human being on the other end of that network connection, however misguided they may appear to be. We’re here to learn from our peers, not yell at each other.

Translation:

> ## Як мені написати хорошу відповідь?
>
> Дякуємо, що знайшли час, щоб внести відповідь. Завдяки допомозі таких людей, як Ви, ми можемо вчитися разом, як спільнота. Ось кілька порад, як зробити Вашу відповідь ладною:
>
> #### Віддячте іншому учаснику
>
> Казати «дякую» — це добре, але в якості відповіді не годиться. Натомість — проголосуйте за відповіді, які допомогли Вам найбільше! Якщо ці відповіді були корисними для Вас, будь ласка, подумайте про подяку ще конструктивнішим способом — надайте власні відповіді на запитання, що ставлять інші.
>
> #### Вас цікавить те саме питання?
>
> Ще немає відповіді на запитання, яке Вас теж цікавить? Допоможіть нам знайти рішення, дослідивши питання, а потім внесіть висновки свого дослідження та все, що Ви намагалися з'ясувати у процесі, як відповідь, нехай і часткову. Таким чином, навіть якщо питання не буде розв'язане, наступний відвідувач матиме більше точок опори. Ви також можете проголосувати за запитання або встановити за нього [винагороду](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), таким чином воно отримає більше уваги.
>
> #### Відповідаючи на запитання
>
> Уважно прочитайте запитання. Про що конкретно воно запитує? Переконайтеся, що Ваша відповідь надає саме цю інформацію — або прийнятну альтернативу їй. Відповідь може бути «не робіть так», але тоді вона також має містити «спробуйте натомість оце». Будь-яка відповідь, що допомагає запитувачу йти у вірному напрямку, є корисною, але намагайтеся зазначати всі обмеження, припущення чи спрощення, що стосуються Вашої відповіді. Стислість є прийнятною, але повніші роз'яснення — кращі.
>
> #### Надавайте контекст для посилань
>
> Посилання на зовнішні ресурси заохочуються, але, будь ласка, додавайте контекст до посилань, щоб Ваші співрозмовники мали певне уявлення, що це за посилання і навіщо воно наведене. Завжди цитуйте найрелевантніші частини важливих ​​посилань на випадок, якщо цільовий сайт буде тимчасово недоступним або зникне назавжди.
>
> #### Пишіть настільки добре, наскільки можете
>
> Ми не очікуємо, щоб кожна відповідь була досконалою, але відповіді з правильними орфографією, пунктуацією та граматикою легше читати. Зазвичай вони також частіше отримують позитивні оцінки. І не забувайте про можливість у будь-який момент повернутися і відредагувати свою відповідь, зробивши її ще кращою.
>
> #### Відповідайте на [добре поставлені](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) запитання
>
> Не на всі запитання можливо чи бажано відповідати. Оберігайте свій душевний спокій і уникайте спроб відповісти на запитання, які…
>
> - …нечіткі, або яким бракує певних подробиць для однозначного окреслення проблеми.
> - …запитують про [погляди](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), а не про факти.
> - …[були вже поставлені](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search) багато разів, і на які вже відповіли.
> - …вимагають забагато вказівок від Вас до повного розв'язання або стосуються відразу декількох питань.
> - …не є запитаннями про українську мову (в тому сенсі, в якому це [означено в довідковому центрі](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).
>
> Не забувайте, що Ви можете редагувати запитання, на які відповідаєте, щоб зробити їх чіткішими та сфокусованішими — це може зменшити ймовірність закриття або видалення запитання.
>
> #### Завжди будьте ввічливими; отримуйте задоволення
>
> Це нормально — не погоджуватись або висловлювати збентеження — але, будь ласка, будьте вихованими. На іншому кінці «дроту» — жива людина, але помилковими  можуть бути судження її. Ми тут, щоб дізнаватися більше від інших, а не лаяти одне одного.

Цей переклад готується для опублікування [тут](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Які в ньому є неточності, немилозвучні моменти чи інші проблеми? Чи, можливо, Ви просто маєте якісь поради щодо його поліпшення?

Пропоную deadline 2017-11-01 — якщо до цього моменту не з'явиться нових обговорень/нарікань, перемістити в «Довідковий центр».

Comment: -1: This post looks like an announce, not a genuine question that encourages answering it. At the bare minimum, it should be re-formatted into a Question and self-Answer parts.

Comment: @bytebuster, вже 2017-11-01. Як щодо додавання [сюди](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)?

Answer (score 3):

Коментарі до розділу

> #### Pay it forward
>
> Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question.
>   Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these
>   answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a
>   more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions
>   your peers have asked here.

Тут йдеться про подяки, тому я би одразу підкреслив це заголовком.

> #### Віддячте іншому учаснику

Далі йдеться про те, що писати відповідь у вигляді "дякую" не є прийнятною? Тоді це треба трошки ясніше означити.

> Казати «дякую» — це добре, але в якості відповіді не годиться.

І тавтологію краще прибрати

> надайте власні відповіді на запитання, що **ставлять** інші.

Comment: З першим і останнім цілком згоден. Щодо другого… Мені здається, що тут кажуть не про те, що «писати відповідь у вигляді "дякую" не є прийнятним» (тут узагалі контекст, здається, такий: починають вони абзац зі «що робити, як Вам хтось допоміг відповідями»; потім різні ступені віддяки, впорядковаті за зростанням рівня конструктивності: сказати «дякую», поставити плюс, написати власну відповідь; тобто до того, щоб писати відповідь самому, вони витіювато приходять лише в кінці абзацу і дивно було б, якби на самому початку вони казали, як саме її треба/не треба писати).

Comment: Мені здається, тут малося на увазі щось на зразок: «це добре — дякувати людям, але самим „дякую“ сит не будеш / одним лише „дякую“ справи не робляться (тут, на SE, словесне „дякую“ — найменш конструктивний спосіб віддяки)». Але не знаю, як це сказати доречніше.

Comment: **Схоже Ви були [праві](//ell.stackexchange.com/q/143855/5811) й у другому пункті**, виправив і це теж.

Answer (score 2):

Коментарі до розділу

> #### Have the same problem?
>
> Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help
>   us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the
>   results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a
>   partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next
>   person has more to go on. You can also vote up the question or set a
>   bounty on it so the question gets more attention.

У першому реченні використано "вас цікавить те саме", а в заголовку — "проблема", тоді як в оригіналі йдеться про одне й те саме. Схоже, що how to писався з думкою про SO, тоді як на мовному сайті "проблема" дійсно звучить не дуже. Чому б тоді не урівняти й заголовок?

> #### Вас цікавить те саме?

"Внесіть ... як часткову відповідь" у мене, як новачка, якщо чесно, викликає непорозуміння: це якийсь особливий вид відповіді, типу десь прапорець тре' поставити? Хоча я розумію, що в оригіналі так само заплутано написано. На жаль, не можу нічого запропонувати натомість.

"матиме більше точок опори" чомусь нагадує сопромат <sub>пробачте, опірмат</sub> :) Може, краще "матиме від чого відштовхнутися"? Суб'єктивно, звісно.

Comment: Дякую. Взагалі мені від початку не подобається друга половина речення «Все ще немає відповіді на якесь запитання, а Вас цікавить те саме?» — якось вона не в'яжеться із першою. Може, краще: «Все ще немає відповіді на якесь запитання, а Вас воно теж цікавить / яке Вас теж цікавить?» — як думаєте? Тоді й у заголовок теж можна поставити щось на кшталт «Вас теж цікавить це питання?» замість абстрактного «Вас цікавить те саме?». Чи, думаєте, краще «те саме?» в обох місцях?

Comment: Якщо замінити «часткову» на «неповну», легше не стане? Чи те саме? Чи надто відхід від суті оригіналу буде?

Comment: @Sasha навіть так: "Все ще немає відповіді на запитання, яке Вас теж цікавить?" ("якесь" тоді буде зайвим) + "Вас теж цікавить це питання?"

Comment: @Sasha а як щодо "внесіть ... як відповідь, нехай і часткову" ?

Comment: Змінив. А щодо «проблема»/«те саме» винесіть, будь ласка, Ваш вердикт. Варіанти: **1. Заголовок:** _(а)_ «Вас цікавить те саме питання?» / _(б)_ «Вас теж цікавить це питання?» / _(в)_ «Вас цікавить те саме?». **2. Початок абзацу:** _(а)_ «Все ще немає відповіді на якесь запитання, яке Вас теж цікавить?» / _(б)_ «Все ще немає відповіді на якесь запитання, а Вас воно теж цікавить?» / _(в)_ «Все ще немає відповіді на якесь запитання, а Вас цікавить те саме?». Я за 1а+2а, а Ви все ще за 1в+2в чи ні?

Comment: @Sasha мені теж подобається 1а+2а, але як вище казав "якесь..яке" ріже вухо. Я би "якесь" викинув.

Comment: Виправлено. Заодно замінив «Все ще» на «ще». Якщо Ви не проти.